# book search engine?

Tags: literature, technology, books

I think that I stumbled upon a web search engine with an index of many esperanto books. You could search for phrases, and it replied with findings in these books, complete with title, author and so on.

I cannot find it anymore. Is my memory betraying me?

Comment: I don't have the names of these on mind, but I think what you're thinking of is a corpus. There are many, but simply searching "Esperanto corpus" should give you more luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you perhaps thinking of the [Tekstaro](http://tekstaro.com/)? I think it would sort of do what you want except that it has a fairly limited selection of books so it’s more useful just to check language usage rather than find a particular title.

Comment: Yes, this was what I meant! Interesting that you find the book selection limited. Now that I now the term “corpus”, I am trying to expand my selection. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Besides the [**Tekstaro**](http://www.tekstaro.com/) I find very useful the [**Corpora Collection**](http://corpora.uni-leipzig.de/en?corpusId=epo_mixed_2012) by the Leipzig University. Apparently you can only search one word at a time. If someone knows how to search more than one word at a time or even sentences, please let us all know.